# Recommendation for PDF "organizer"

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, software

I am looking for a PDF library organizer / tool. The requirements are:

1. I can create "shelves" where I could sort the PDFs by topics.
2. I could access it both from my iPad and from my Mac or maybe even the iPhone.
3. If possible (not necessary), there should be an easy way to annotate it on the iPad with the pen.

I never did find quite an organizer like this. I am looking to do it for school papers that I read.

Thank you.

Comment: [Application for managing a pdf document library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/application-for-managing-a-pdf-document-library?rq=1) Just saw this very similar question from the past. you can have your question closed and even merged with this one by raising a mod attention flag, if they agree. But the chances are low, it is from 2010.

Comment: @ankii The answer on that link might help the OP, but with current versions of iOS and macOS the  OP doesn't really need an application at all (something which the question from 2010 doesn't allow as it asks for things which still ain't possible natively).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you just tried using iCloud drive on the Mac and the "Files" app on the phone/iPad, with shelves represented by sub-folders?

Apps are opened and marked in Preview on the Mac and in-app markup is allowed in Files.

All changes are synced. Elegant. Free. Baked-in using no extra apps.

Answer (score 1):

The native Books app by Apple. I find all tick boxes you mentioned checked.

[image]

Only problem on iOS is this:

- [Downloaded ibooks get deleted when icloud sync is turned off, even under airplane mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378242/downloaded-ibooks-get-deleted-when-icloud-sync-is-turned-off-even-under-airplan/378260#378260)
- [Books automatically deletes my books when offline, and when there is enough space on device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344271/books-automatically-deletes-my-books-when-offline-and-when-there-is-enough-spac?noredirect=1&lq=1)